# Overlapping lettrines fail with optfile.cfl

Tags: lettrine

I've modified the code found [here](http://tex-talk.net/2011/08/putting-colors-in-initials/) that uses rlap to write two lettrines, one atop the other. The font I want to use happens to allow for three colors, so I've nested another one on there. It works without a supplemental lettrine.cfg file. It works with such a file if the file doesn't itself reference an optfile.cfl file. However, if lettrine.cfg does point to optfile.cfl, it fails with "Missing \endcsname inserted." How can I get it to work in this last instance?

Here's an ugly, illustrative MWE with the standard font.

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}% uncomment to reproduce error - cfr
\begin{filecontents}{lettrine.cfg}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{4}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{-0.1ex}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0ex}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLhang}{0.06}
\LettrineRealHeighttrue
\renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsFile}{optfile.cfl}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{optfile.cfl}
\LettrineOptionsFor{X}{findent=6ex}
\LettrineOptionsFor{Y}{findent=5ex}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{Steel}{HTML}{66676A}
\definecolor{Mgold}{HTML}{D4AF37}
\definecolor{Offblack}{HTML}{1E1E1E}

\newcommand{\LettrineBackColor}{Mgold}
\newcommand{\LettrineDecoColor}{Steel}
\newcommand{\LettrineLetterColor}{Offblack}

\newcommand{\layerlettrine}[3][]{%
\lettrine[#1]{%
\rlap{\rlap{\color{\LettrineDecoColor} #2}%
     {\color{\LettrineBackColor} \em{#2}}}%
     {\color{\LettrineLetterColor}\lowercase{#2}}}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{X}{omot} \lipsum[1]

\layerlettrine{Y}{olanda} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Fails at:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lipsum\lipsum.sty")
No file mwe_lettrine.aux.
(optfile.cfl) (optfile.cfl)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \hbox 
l.25 \layerlettrine{Y}{olanda}
                               \lipsum[2]
?
```

Comment: Welcome! `\em` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: I've edited your code so it is easier to see the error and reproduce it. You can, of course, roll-back if you don't like it.

Comment: I don't think the package is really prepared for this kind of thing. The combination is just throwing too much at it, given the way it handles the options from the `cfl` file. (I'm not really sure why it does things the way it does, but I don't think it is going to be able to handle the option setting plus the EB Garamond stuff.) However, I may be completely wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. I will add that the function does work if the desired options are added as `\layerlettrine[findent=4em]{Y}{olanda} \lipsum[2]`, but that seems not to be the preferred way. I'll kludge if I must though.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, I suggest emailing the package author.